# why "separate" and "unite" function don´t not work in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I used the function `separate` and `unite` to clean some data but they don´t seem to work

I've been trying to separate a column string into two columns using `dplyr`. The function is quite easy and I don't know why it does not work. 
The variable (column) I want to separate is `season` which contains values of “MAD_S1, KGA_S1” etc. (thousands of records, but there are 6 categories, all separated by the “_S1”; raw data has been inspected and all follow the same syntax). Therefore, I applied

```
separate(six_sites_spp, season, c("code_loc","season1"), sep = "_")
```

I have tried more explicit script such as:

```
separate(six_sites_spp, 
     col = "season",
     into = c("code_loc", "season1"),
     sep = "_")
```

but nothing either.

I have updated the `dplyr` versions, and tried several things. If I use `unite` instead to merge two columns, it does not work either. I resolved this by using the classic `paste` function, but not for the splitting; I do however want to know why `dplyr` does not work (this is a great package and for some reason other commands are not working either).

Would anyone be able to provide feedback on this, please? Is it a possible “bug” or something within my system (Windows10, HP envi)? Do I need another package simultaneously (I also use `tidyr` in the same script)? Any version mismatch (my R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)? When I run the code it does something internally, as I see it runs the commands, but the output is the same data frame (i.e. no new variables `code_loc`, `season1`.

Many thanks in advance.

*there are no error messages

Comment: Please include a portion of your data in your question (use `dput` to make it easy to import), so that other can try to reproduce your problem

Comment: solved, thank you for your willingness to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you mention no error message, I assume the function works properly but you simply fail to save the output.

Usually `dplyr` flows like this:

```r
library(dplyr)
six_sites_spp %>%
    separate(season, c("code_loc", "season1"), sep = "_")) %>%
    {.} -> six_sites_spp # This saves the changed data frame under the old name
```

Alternatively, this works as well:

```r
six_sites_spp <- separate(six_sites_spp,season, c("code_loc", "season1"), sep = "_"))
```

Naturally you could also save the changed data frame under a new name to preserve the original data.

Comment: Dear Zeiram, this worked well, so maybe the home-take message is to always put an object name before performing any function (or use the {.} bit. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @lep Happy to help, if my answer solved your issue, you might want to mark it as answered. As to your take-home message, this depends on what you want to do. But if you want to change/mutate a df this change needs to be saved somewhere. Additionally `dplyr` functions are designed to work in the pipe-flow so I suggest getting familiar with it. The `{.} -> df`hacks works really well for me because I can perform changes, look at them and only if I am satisfied save them at the end. If you leave the statement out and end at the function you will still see what `separate`did to your df.